# iOS: renderInContext is rendering a window's contents at -90 degrees?

Tags: ios, ipad

I am trying to get external screen support up and running. Unfortunately the method I am using to render a window into a CGContextRef is resulting in the window being rotated (without my having specified any rotation) at -90 degrees.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext (extwin.bounds.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

 if ([window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
    {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        [[window layer] renderInContext:context];
        CGContextRestoreGState (context);
        break;
}
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this? I have only used core graphics for basic drawing, not for transforms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The base coordinate system for CoreGraphics is not the same as the base coordinate system for UIKit. And in fact, it's different on different devices. It sounds like you need to figure out what the base coordinate system is on your particular device, then apply a CTM transformation to your context before attempting to render the window layer. This will let you transform the base coordinate system from CoreGraphics to be the same as what you're expecting.

To clarify, when you create a new context, the coordinate system is fully-documented. However, the coordinate system used by the layer of a window is going to match the base CoreGraphics coordinate system for the screen (which is what's different on different devices). This needs to be translated back to match the coordinate system for your context, and you can do that by figuring out the right affine transformation, and applying that to your context with [`CGContextConcatCTM()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-F17016) and related functions.

Comment: @Mithras: Honestly, I'm not really sure. Perhaps `window.transform` will be all you need.

Comment: I tried that... it was actually included in the sample code before I edited it and posted a shorter version above.

Comment: @Mithras: Why exactly are you trying to draw a window's layer into a graphics context anyway? Normally external screen support is done by throwing up a second window onto the second screen and setting up a view hierarchy there.

Comment: @Mithras: You could also try drawing all of the window's sub-layers into your context, instead of drawing the window itself. That should allow you to simply transform your context to match the window's coordinate system (i.e. the default UIKit coordinate system).

Comment: my GUI is complex. There is not enough free RAM to have a second GUI just for the external display.

Comment: But I *am* drawing all my GUI's windows into the external context.